# Flatten records in list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of records such as:

```
[{"id": "1",
  "name": "somename",
  "add1": "abc",
  "add2": "def",
  "account1": "223",
  "account2": "231"},
 {"id": "2",
  "name": "somename",
  "add1": "jkl",
  "add2": "efg",
  "account1": "678",
  "account2": "345"},
 {"id": "1",
  "name": "somename",
  "add1": "pqr",
  "add2": "stu",
  "account1": "123",
  "account2": "456"},
 {"id": "2",
  "name": "somename",
  "add1": "mno",
  "add2": "wxy",
  "account1": "456",
  "account2": "789"}]
```

Now, I want to group the records in such a way:

```
[{"id: "1",
  "name": "somename",
  "address": [{"add1": "abc", "add2": "def"},
              {"add1": "pqr", "add2": "stu"}],
  "account": [{"account1": "223", "account2": "231"},
              {"account1": "123", "account2": "456"}]},
 {"id: "2",
  "name": "somename",
  "address": [{"add1":"jkl", "add2":"efg"},
              {"add1":"mno", "add2":"wxy"}],
  "account": [{"account1":"678", "account2":"345"},
              {"account1":"456", "account2":"789"}]}]
```

I am unable to do so as I am new to python.

Comment: So you want to group information by the `id` and `name` keys? Create a dictionary, use the `id` value as a key, and collect the other values in lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, Well commented. Hope you will learn from here,
[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/58GC9S8L)